# Widevine DRM test stream

Tags: drm, android-drm

I am trying to test a Chromecast application for DRM support. I have implemented the receiver and sender and wanted to find a test drm stream and a license url. Where can I find a test stream and a license URL to decrypt that stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a sample app hosted here:

http://www.videws.com/eureka/ecp/

There are a SS with PlayReady and another MPEG-DASH with Widevine streams that you can give it a try.  However there might be CORS limitation.  Give it a try.

Comment: Actually, what I noticed about that DRM exmaple (tears.mpd) MPEG-DASH with Widevine is that the material plays with or without setting the DRM license URL. Try to load the media without setting the license URL and it still plays the media. If it is DRM ecripted, shouldn't it not play the material if I dont set the license URL?

Comment: The sample got updated there:

Comment: 1) Media Player Library 1.0 was just released.  Please update your code accordingly.  See this G+ post for more detail https://plus.google.com/+ShawnShen/posts/fqzAgEGeFWC 2) The MPEG-DASH stream was updated to:http://storage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/dash/CarWidevine/car.mpd